# flags need an argument keybase chat api example

Tags: keybase

I'am trying to test the example of the keybase chat api :

```
 echo "{'method': 'send', 'params': {'options': {'channel': {'name': 'you', 'public': true}, 'message': {'body': 'Still going...'}}}}" | keybase chat api -m
```

but all i got is this error message :

```
Error parsing command line arguments: flag needs an argument: -m
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

You can try following commands for keybase chat API/keybase-cli:

```
>keybase chat send <username> <your message>
>keybase chat read <username/channel>
```

Other examples given in `help` will work like the above commands. No need to pass JSON here.

Answer (score 0):

The `-m` flag is intended to take a JSON string directly instead of reading from STDIN, which is what your `echo` statement is passing.

If you want to read from `echo`, simply remove the `-m` flag entirely. If you wish to use the `-m` flag and read from a string, try the following format:

```bash
keybase chat api -m "{'method': 'send', 'params': {'options': {'channel': {'name': 'you', 'public': true}, 'message': {'body': 'Still going...'}}}}"
```